# How to write simple regex in golang?

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to write regexp that returns the substring for string that begins with dot and until first space. But I am new in regular expressions, so I tried something
 like that and it doesn't work at all:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("\\.* ")
    fmt.Printf(re.FindString(".d 1000=11,12")) // Must return d
    fmt.Printf(re.FindString("e 2000=11"))     // Must return nothing or ""
    fmt.Printf(re.FindString(".e2000=11"))     // Must return nothing or ""
}
```

this code just white 3 white space in golang. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `regexp.MustCompile("\\..*\\s")` works for me, at least for your provided examples.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While `*` is the wildcard in glob matching, it's not the wildcard in regex. In regex, `.` is the wildcard and `*` means repetition of 0 or more times. You probably want:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("\\..* ")
```

[go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/jXhhO__Dkj)

But you might notice that it's also returning the dot and space. You can use `FindStringSubmatch` and use a capture group to fix this, and you can use backsticks so that you don't have to double escape things:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\.(.*) `)
match := re.FindStringSubmatch(".d 1000=11,12")
if len(match) != 0 {fmt.Printf("1. %s\n", match[1])}
```

[go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/6J3kk5S8yo)

Though I would prefer using `\S*` (matches non-space characters) instead of `.*` to get this match, since it'll reduce the possible backtracking:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`\.(\S*) `)
```

[go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/rZUW_7s6LY)

Comment: Why are you editing out playground links to the code? Via the edit history those links still work perfect well.

Comment: @DaveC Are they? I get 'forbidden' when I follow the links now, and play.golang.org does not have the button to save code anymore (pic: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sQCu7.png)

Comment: @DaveC Looks like it's on my side. There's some firewall maybe =/ I'll roll back

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 characters you write `\\` mean that you're escaping backslash, so you're expecting backslash as the first character. You should write `^\..*?` instead:

- ^ - means beginning
- \. - means escaping dot (so together with one above means that you expect dot as the first character)
- .*? - any character (dot), any number of them (asterisk), not greedy (question mark) until space (space)

Non-greedy means that it will stop at first space not at the last one